# Arduino char* array[] : "vanishing" characters

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I'm using a char* array[] to store serial printed data.

However, the data are "vanishing" from the array.

The problem seems to occur when I print the same var several times.

**Serial output :**

```
Hello world !
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
0 - Archivage de : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Affichage de l'historique : 
0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
1 - Archivage de : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Affichage de l'historique : 
0Lorem ip
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2 - Archivage de : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Affichage de l'historique : 
0Lorem ip
1Lore
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Affichage de l'historique : 
0Lorem ip
1Lore
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

**Arduino sketch :**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

#include <shutterSerial.h>

ShutterSerial s = ShutterSerial();

void setup() {

  s.begin(115200);
  s.setVerboseLevel(DEBUG);
  String test("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
  s.print("Hello world !", INFO, true);
  s.print(test, INFO, true);
  s.print(test, INFO, true);
  s.print(test, INFO, true);


  s.historique_print();

}


void loop() {
}
```

**shutterSerial.h**

```
#ifndef shutterSerial
#define shutterSerial

#include <SPI.h>

#define HISTORYSIZE 20

enum Level {
  ERROR,
  INFO,
  STACK,
  DEBUG,
  };

class ShutterSerial {

  public:

    /*Constructeur*/
    ShutterSerial();
    static void begin(unsigned int baudRate);

    static void setVerboseLevel(unsigned int level);
    static unsigned int getVerboseLevel();

    static void print(String msg, int level, bool crlf);
    static void print(int msg, int level, bool crlf);
    static void print(char* msg, int level, bool crlf);

    static void historique_reset();
    /*Historique des messages séries. On ne conserve que les messages d'INFO et d'ERROR*/
    static char* _historique[HISTORYSIZE];
    static void historique_put(char* nouveau);
    static void historique_print();
    static unsigned int _compteur;

    static char* intToCharArray(int value, bool crlf);

  private:
    static Level _verbosite;

};
#endif
```

**shutterSerial.cpp**

```
#include "shutterSerial.h"

ShutterSerial::ShutterSerial() {}

/*Initialisation du niveau de verbosité à INFO*/
Level ShutterSerial::_verbosite = INFO;

char* ShutterSerial::_historique[HISTORYSIZE];
unsigned int ShutterSerial::_compteur = 0;
static char temp[128];


void ShutterSerial::begin(unsigned int baudRate) {
  Serial.begin(baudRate);
  /*Ces deux lignes permettent d'éviter de perdre le premier caractère affiché
  L'arduino à tendance à ne pas afficher le premier caractère.
  */
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("");
}

unsigned int ShutterSerial::getVerboseLevel() {
  return (unsigned int)_verbosite;
}

void ShutterSerial::setVerboseLevel(unsigned int level) {
  _verbosite = (Level) level;
}

void ShutterSerial::print(String msg, int level, bool crlf) {
  if(level <= _verbosite) {
    if (crlf) {
      Serial.println(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        msg += "\n";
        msg.toCharArray(temp, msg.length());
        historique_put(temp);
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.print(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        msg.toCharArray(temp, msg.length());
        historique_put(temp);
      }
    }
  }
}
void ShutterSerial::print(int msg, int level, bool crlf) {
  if(level <= _verbosite) {
    if (crlf) {
      Serial.println(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        // historique_put(ShutterSerial::intToCharArray(msg, true));
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.print(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        // historique_put(ShutterSerial::intToCharArray(msg, false));
      }
    }
  }
}
void ShutterSerial::print(char* msg, int level, bool crlf) {
  if(level <= _verbosite) {
    if (crlf) {
      Serial.println(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        // strcat(msg, "\n");
        // historique_put(msg);
      }
    }
    else {
      Serial.print(msg);
      if(level <= INFO) {
        // historique_put(msg);
      }
    }
  }
}


/*Manipulation de l'historique*/

void ShutterSerial::historique_reset() {
  _compteur = 0;
}

void ShutterSerial::historique_put(char* nouveau) {
  Serial.print(_compteur);
  Serial.print(" - Archivage de : ");
  Serial.println(nouveau);
  _historique[_compteur] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(nouveau) + 1));
  memcpy(_historique[_compteur], nouveau, strlen(nouveau) + 1);
  _compteur = _compteur + 1;
  historique_print();

}

void ShutterSerial::historique_print() {
  int cpt = 0;
  Serial.println("Affichage de l'historique : ");

  if(_compteur > 0) {
    for(cpt = 0; cpt < _compteur; cpt++) {
      Serial.print(cpt);
      Serial.println(_historique[cpt]);
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("L'historique est vide.");
  }
}

char* ShutterSerial::intToCharArray(int value, bool crlf) {
  char* convertedValue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  if(crlf) {
    sprintf(convertedValue, "%d\n", value);
  }
  else {
    sprintf(convertedValue, "%d", value);
  }
  return convertedValue;
}
```

Comment: Why use malloc and not new -- or better, make_unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's expand this line for more readability.

```
_historique[_compteur] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(nouveau) + 1));

_historique[_compteur] = (char*)malloc(    sizeof( strlen(nouveau) + 1 )    );
```

Here you are taking the `sizeof( strlen(nouveau) + 1 )` which is equal to `sizeof(int)` !

This line should be:

```
_historique[_compteur] = (char*)malloc( (strlen(nouveau) + 1) * sizeof(char)  );
```

I hope it is readable!